# Should I balance the test set for predicting probabilities in binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-classification

In my dataset I have 75 % of "0" class instances and 25 % of "1" class. It a real world ratio between classess. I balanced my training set, and trained the model.

Then, depending on whether my test sample is also balanced or not my model perfomance metrics are different:

in case of unbalanced test set: ROC AUC=0.7, F1score =0.4, PR AUC=0.39

in case of balanced test set: ROC AUC =0.7, F1score=0.87, PR AUC=0.7

In which case I can find real perfomance of my model? And what metric should I use?

Comment: Do the 2 classes have different misclassification cost?

Comment: Good news! Class imbalance is not a problem!
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: @Sammy class "1" misclassification is worse.